# Time Complexity of substr inside a Recursive Function

Tags: c++, recursion, stl

> In the function below, the time complexity of substr() is O(n) which is inside the recursive function and the recursive call being O(n), **will the time complexity of the entire block be O(n^2) then?**

```
void replacePi(string s) {
    if(s.length() == 0) {       // base case
        return;
    }
    if(s[0] == 'p' && s[1] == 'i') {
        cout << "3.14";
        string remaining = s.substr(2); //remaining substring
        replacePi(remaining);
    } else {
        cout << s[0];
        replacePi(s.substr(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself will recursion split into multiple recursions or not? And what will that mean for the complexities?  Should they be added or multiplied.

Comment: They should be added right?.

Comment: Yes, then remove all the constants and lower level orders from the order to get the final order. Which will be?

Comment: Yes that is it :)

Comment: If the initial length is N, you're (in the worst case) going to copy N-1 + N-2 + N- 3 + ... + 1 characters. That sum is (N - 1) * N / 2, which is O(n^2),

Comment: Note that there is a bug where you look at the second element without checking that it exists first.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `replacePi` is taking a string length of either `n-2` or `n-1` for `n` number of times. So if you have a string of length `n` - then the complexity would be :

```
o(n * ((n-2) or (n-1))) 
=> o(n * n) 
=> o(n^2)
```